# How to Improve XML read write performance

Tags: .net, xml, performance

I have two .NET applications running independently(can start in any order, or may be only one running) which uses XML as data store. So both applications can read and write to XML file.
To keep the data updated , i'm loading the XML file every time from the disk before read and write operations. And i'm using XPath query for querying the particular node.
Now there is performance issue observed in this method as there are read and write requests on XML every second from one application(uses polling, and cannot be changed)
I'm not sure what exactly is causing the performance hit, but i believe its continuous read write.

I tried using memory mapped files from .NET 4.0 but i'm restricted to use .NET 3.5 and not any higher versions.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Note : XML nodes have some common attributes , different number of attributes and one ID which i use for XPath querying.

Comment: Are you sure you can't implement other data source like Sql Server Compact? Why can't you change it?

Comment: Did you consider using something different than xml for that use? maybe memcached (http://memcached.org/)? sql?
if you have to use xml, try using XmlReader and XmlWriter

Comment: If you cant change the first application, your options are very limited. Bad design leads to bad performance.

Comment: No major design changes accepted, so have to stick with XML at-least for a while. And i can't change the first application because its legacy and expected to work like that.

Comment: And to add, the XML file is not so big, only about 60 nodes with approx 10 attributes each

Answer (score 3):

**IF** you're sure that performance hit comes from I/O and you can't change both application there is really a little you can do.

First solution with zero changes to existing application code: use a [RAM disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk). If they're using that file as *shared memory* you can do it without any other change. If data is persistent you may need to perform a background copy to another media after each writing. Performance won't be as good as a true shared memory but at least you won't have to wait for slow I/O operations.

Second solution with changes only in the application that must read data: often the parsing of a XML file is pretty slow (specially if you're using `XmlDocument` and the file isn't very little). In this case, using `XmlReader`, you have to make your read code more complicated and to forget about XPath queries but its performance will be many times better than `XmlDocument` and it won't slow down increasing the file size.

Small (or not so small) updates: if code of the second application (I guess the one that will read the file) can be changed you can do a little to improve its performance. First of all do not read the file each time. Check its timestamp, register a `FileSystemWatcher` for that file or whatever else but do not read/parse file each time. When you did this you can go one step forward: read/parse the file only when it changes, prepare your `XmlDocument` on background (another thread) and make it available for polling requests. If requests are *spaced* they may even see a very quick response time (but profile performance of `XmlDocument` XPath query for your typical file).

**EDIT**: [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257405) you can find a RAM disk provided by Microsoft. It's pretty simple and naive but usually you/we don't need much more than that. Moreover it's an example on the DDK so you'll get source code too (in this case...just for fun).

Comment: +1 - RAM disk is one of few things that one could do with such a misdesigned application, regardless of how badly designed it is.

Comment: By RAM disk , do you mean shared files / in-memory files?

Comment: No, RAM disk is a virtual disk that stay in memory. Application will see as a normal drive (added a link).

Comment: Any links to RAM disk implementation in .NET using C#?

Comment: If you do not need something _special_ you can use the RAM disk provided by Microsoft in the DDK: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257405 (it's a DDK example so you'll get source code too).

Answer (score 2):

XML is not designed for heavy querying. If you need to do this, consider using a database. [SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx) could be a good alternative. If you need to stick with XML though and need to work with large files and need performance consider using [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx)/[XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) which are not loading the entire file into memory and are pretty fast.

Comment: -1: If they cannot change the app, how a database might help?

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice this constraint. XmlReader/XmlWriter as mentioned in my answer are the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading the XML file very time, just read it the first time and also get the last modified time for the file.

Whenver you need to know if the data is up to date, just check the modified time of the file, and only read the file again if it really has changed.

Comment: If that app *really* writes to the file every second, this won't help much.  But this can be easily checked before writing such code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't poll the file. Read it once and keep it in-memory, then use `FileSystemWatcher` to reload it *only* when it changes.

Or alternatively, read the modification timestamp and only reload the file if the timestamp changed.

---

Also, when reading the file, make sure you lock it non-exclusively so other readers are not blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the file exclusively.  The other application may crash, but if it does not crash, you will know one thing for sure: it cannot invoke much I/O load in one cycle on the shared file, because all its access attempts will fail immediately.

Hopefully it will just wait a second and retry, and that should work well for you.

```
using (Stream iStream = File.Open("myfile.xml",
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
    ...
}
```